# How to kill a batch file with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, file-handling, popen

How could I stop a running file or kill it (.bat file) ?

I used a code in function to open it :

```
p = subprocess.Popen(str(filepath), shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

so I want to make another function that kills/close the same file but I need help with that

I tried something like that :|

```
p = subprocess.Popen('exit ' + str(filepath), shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

I need your help please and Thanks ♥

Comment: `p.terminate()` and `p.kill()`

Comment: Your batch file shouldn't be running if it was properly used to start your server. What you should be looking at, therefore, is stopping the server, not the batch file. Also why could you not both start and stop the server from python, I don't understand why a batch file would be required for your task at all!

Comment: I'm a FiveM server owner and I'm not online all the time so I'm trying to make a script that be in my vps -- if an admin want to start the server and I'm not there he just need to write a command in the discord and it starts the server by the code that is running the discord bot in my vps -- so sometimes they need to restart the server : they have to stop the server and reopen it and all this by this batch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal to close a opened programe you can use: **taskkill /IM AppName >nul**
Example: **taskkill /IM notepad++.exe >nul**

Now you can use os library to type that:

```py
#// Import
import os

#// Global Var's
appName:str = "notepad++"
appExtension:str = "exe"

#// Logic
os.system(f'cmd /c "taskkill /IM {appName}.{appExtension} >nul"')
```